# precision error in summation addition/subtraction (of mass)

Tags: c++, precision

How to cache summation of all floating point values in a certain list in a way that can avoid precision error?

### Example

I have mass of many physic shapes : `m1`,`m2`,`m3`,...
Those shapes join together into a big body with mass `M` = `m1`+`m2`+`m3`+....
I have to request mass of the big body frequently, so I cache `M`.

Now, I have responsibility to update  `M` as appropriate.

When I add a shape with mass = `mi` :-

```
M += mi;
```

When I remove a shape with mass = `mi` :-

```
M -= mi;
```

### Problem

After program add/remove shapes for some time,
`M` become far and far away from the correct summation. (`m1`+`m2`+`m3`+....)

As a result, my program finally executes abnormally.
No doubt, the symptom will show faster if mass ratio of some pair `mi` and `mj` is very low or very high.

### Question

How to professionally alleviate this numerical issue?

In other words :-
Should I never cache the summation, `M`, in the first place?
Should I recalculate the summation every time (in a brute force style) after a small shape was added/removed, or (may be) just before some callers request `M`?

I have read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm, it can only postpone the issue.

Comment: The standard way is using higher precision for intermediate results. E.g. use `double` if the input is `float`. You will lose precision of double but the float value will be intact.

Comment: @GMichael - double can make the problem less severe, but you can try to add 1e0 + 1e20 with `float` or `double` and you will still get the wrong answer (i.e. you will get `1e20`, not 100000000000000000001)

Comment: @MarkLakata I saw your answer. You're correct in theory. But it has nothing to do with practice. Nobody will sum masses of protons and the sun. Any experiment operates with masses in the same range and, therefore, my answer is relevant.

Comment: It's not summing protoins and suns that is the issue, it is summing many protons. It only takes 1e8 protons summed together to the point where the sum is bogus if the result is `float`. Yes, you can extend it to 1e16 protons if you use `double` ...  My point is that simply using `double` doesn't automatically fix the problem, if just kicks the problem down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the range of masses, you could consider using *fixed point* arithmetic, and using `int64_t` which will give you 19.5 digits of accuracy, and as long as you never overflow, summation and subtraction can be done in any order and always be precise.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that floating point results are order dependent if the exponents differ. For example, if you do

```
1e0 + 1e20 - 1e20
```

you'll get

```
0.0
```

because `1e0 + 1e20 == 1e20`. But if you did

```
1e20 - 1e20 + 1e0
```

you'll get

```
1e0
```

So in general, you should always sum up the masses and never subtract. And should sum up the lowest values first, so that they have a chance of affecting the final result. If you sum up the largest values first, then the small values will never change the sum.

Depending on how many numbers you need to add, you could cache the masses into groups, and only re-sum the group that is affected, and then combine the masses of the groups. I assume you have lots of bodies here, so the summation might be costly (i.e. you are adding a million bodies or something like that).

But if you are only summing a small number, it might not be worth the effort to optimize it. You should write your code first so that is works, then profile it to find the hot spots. If you are doing physical simulations, things like division or square roots are going to be *way* more expensive than addition.

Comment: "cache the masses into groups" is a great idea.  Thank!   +1

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that you are assuming floating point types (`float`, `double`, or whatever it is you are using) represents real numbers.   They don't - they represent a discrete approximation .... a `double` typically has a precision to 15-17 significant figures, and a `float` typically has a precision of about 7 or 8 significant figures.

This means a lot of values you store will be stored approximately (i.e. with an associated error in comparison with the value you intend).   For example, `0.1` cannot be stored exactly in floating point (since it cannot be represented as a sum of negative powers of `2` - which is, practically, how the mantissa in floating point types is typically represented).

The next effect is that errors propagate.   Any addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponentiation, etc has operands with potential error, and those errors propagate in the result - possibly magnified, possibly attenuated.    The "professional" approach to handling this is to order operations to reduce propagation of errors (and to predict what the resultant errors will be, rather than assuming exact calculations).

A third effect is that adding or subtracting large and small values introduces error.  So `1.0` + `1.0e25` will give a result of `1.0e25`.   Doing repeated additions to get a result then subtractions and re-additions to maintain a value propagates these types of errors - the order of operations, again matters.    So `1.0 + 1.0e25 - 1.0e25` (assuming operations are done left to right) will give a result of (approximately) zero,  whereas `1.0e25 - 1.0e25 + 1.0` will give a result of (approximately) `1.0`.    This is probably what you are seeing (since mass in physical calculations can be very large or very small).     The solution is not to try to optimise a result the way you are, but to redo the addition each time, or to order the masses (and other associated calculations) in some way.     This is an example of where it is worth accepting a performance hit to reduce chances of erroneous calculations.